# reordering table by a field with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to reorder the data of a table by a field.

The only way I know is creating a new table and passing all data (except the primary key `id`) from the old table to the new one ordering by id_temp:

```
INSERT INTO db1.ticket id_temp, text, answer_timestamp, mileage , distance_unit,
 troubles, error_codes, controls, answer_text, answer_pdf, answer_pdf_link,
 estimated_duration, real_duration, delete_operator_id, request_type_id,
 request_properties_id, category_id, operator_id, language_id, deleted_at,
 created_at, updated_at
SELECT (id_temp, text, answer_timestamp, mileage, distance_unit, troubles,
 error_codes, controls, answer_text, answer_pdf, answer_pdf_link,
 estimated_duration, real_duration, delete_operator_id, request_type_id, 
 request_properties_id, category_id, operator_id, language_id, deleted_at, 
 created_at, updated_at) 
FROM db1.ticket_temp order by id_temp;
```

However this method looks to me very heavy.

Is it another way to reorder the data in a table without creating a new one?

Comment: Remove the parentheses from `SELECT (id_temp, ....) FROM`

Comment: FWIW it is not related to the MySQL version. Using parentheses in the way you were doing would cause the same error on any version of MySQL (or any other implementation of SQL).

Comment: You have changed the title of this question to something completely unrelated to the original question. The original question was a duplicate of an old question, and this question is now closed. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The select list should not be surrounded by parenthesis. Additionally, note that tables are intrinsically unordered sets, so inserting with an `order by` clause is probably not very useful:

```sql
INSERT INTO db1.ticket (id_temp, text, answer_timestamp, mileage ,distance_unit ,troubles ,error_codes , controls, answer_text, answer_pdf, answer_pdf_link, estimated_duration, real_duration, delete_operator_id, request_type_id, request_properties_id, category_id, operator_id, language_id, deleted_at, created_at, updated_at)
SELECT id_temp, text, answer_timestamp, mileage ,distance_unit ,troubles ,error_codes , controls, answer_text, answer_pdf, answer_pdf_link, estimated_duration, real_duration, delete_operator_id, request_type_id, request_properties_id, category_id, operator_id, language_id, deleted_at, created_at, updated_at
FROM db1.ticket_temp
```

Comment: So how can I transfer the data from one table to another one ordering by id_temp? The aim of the transfer is that.